# double integral on a bounded domain

Tags: polar-coordinates

Can you help me with this exercise? I did it like this but I'm not sure if until now it is correct:

Integral of $f(x,y) = x$ on $\{x^2+(y-1)^2\geq1; (x-1)^2+y^2 \leq 1\}$

I used polar coordinates
$x = ρ\cosθ$, $y= ρ\sinθ$

With this substitution I found the integration extremes are now: $2\cosθ\leqρ\leq2\sinθ$ and $θ$ between $0$ and $\pi/2$.

The integral instead became $ρ^2\cosθ.$

Is that correct?

Comment: what about the section of the circle below the x axis?  $\theta\in[-\frac {\pi}{2}, \frac {\pi}{2}]$ but then one of the circles is not in play for half the integration.  $\rho\ge \max (2\cos\theta, 0).$

Comment: The section of the circle below the x-axis is not in the integration domain.

Comment: I did not understand why ρ≥max(2cosθ,0).

Comment: Nothing indicates in what is posted that the section of the circle below the x-axis is out of scope.

Comment: Excuse me, I drew the drawing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite. You have$$x^2+(y-1)^2\geqslant0\iff\rho^2\geqslant2\rho\sin\theta\iff\rho\geqslant 2\sin\theta$$and$$(x-1)^2+y^2\leqslant0\iff\rho^2\leqslant2\rho\cos\theta\iff\rho\leqslant2\cos\theta.$$If $\theta\in\left[-\frac\pi2,0\right]$, then $\rho\geqslant2\sin\theta$ becomes $\rho\geqslant0$. So, your integral should be$$\int_{-\pi/2}^0\int_0^{2\cos\theta}\rho^2\cos\theta\,\mathrm d\rho\,\mathrm d\theta+\int_0^{\pi/4}\int_{2\sin\theta}^{2\cos\theta}\rho^2\cos\theta\,\mathrm dr\,\mathrm d\theta.$$

Comment: Thanks for the speed in responding. I have two questions:
1) "If θ∈ [−π / 2,0], then r⩾2sinθ becomes r⩾0" holds because if If θ∈ [−π / 2,0] then 2sinθ is negative so I have to take r⩾0?
2) I didn't understand how I find π / 4.

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) The number $\frac\pi4$ is the point at which $2\cos\theta=2\sin\theta$. And if $\theta\in\left(\frac\pi4,\frac\pi2\right]$, then $2\cos\theta<2\sin\theta$, and therefore there is no $\rho$ such that $2\sin\theta\leqslant\rho\leqslant2\cos\theta$.

Comment: everything is clear. thank you very much!

Comment: I suggest that you mark one of the answers as the accepted one.

Comment: it's the first time I've asked a question. how to do it ?

Comment: Just click on the ✓ sign.

Comment: I'm sorry but there isn't.. where it is?

Comment: To the left of your screen, right below the triangle pointing down.

Answer (score 0):

Circle A: $(x-1)^2 + y^2 = 1 \implies x^2 + y^2 = 2x$. Also note the circle is in fourth and first quadrant. So in polar coordinates, $r = 2 \cos\theta, -\pi/2 \leq \theta \leq \pi/2$

Circle B: $x^2 + (y-1)^2 = 1 \implies x^2 + y^2 = 2y$. The circle is in first and second quadrant. So in polar coordinates, $r = 2 \sin\theta, 0 \leq \theta \leq \pi$

Now given the inequalities, the region is inside circle $A$ and outside circle $B$ which is the shaded region in the diagram.

[image]

Also note that at the intersection of both circle,
$r = 2 \cos\theta = 2\sin\theta \implies \theta = \pi/4$.

So set it up as split integrals where

(i) for $- \pi/2 \leq \theta \leq 0, 0 \leq r \leq 2 \cos\theta$
(ii) $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi/4, 2\sin\theta \leq r \leq 2\cos\theta$.

Comment: Thank you very much, with the drawing it is very clear. However, I didn't understand how to find π / 4

Comment: Where circles intersect, both radius are equal. So $2 \sin \theta = 2 \cos\theta$ or $\tan\theta = 1$ which happens at $\theta = \pi/4$

Comment: everything is clear. thank you very much!

Comment: @MartinaTrapasso you are welcome. Let me know if any further questions.